# Centralizing actions not working in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to perform some clean up as users go from one component to another. In order to keep it simple and consitent, I created a centralized action creator like below:

```
import { cleanUpX } from 'moduleX';
import { cleanUpY } from 'moduleY';
import { cleanUpZ } from 'moduleZ';

export const cleanUp = () => {

   cleanUpX();
   cleanUpY();
   cleanUpZ();
}
```

I then call this action creator in the `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method of my components:

```
class MyComponent1 extends Component {

   ... Code omitted for brevity
   componentWillUnmount() {

      this.props.actions.cleanUp();
   }
}
```

Even though I hit `cleanUp()` and each individual action creator inside it, I don't hit their respective reducers.

In other words, I see that I hit `cleanUpY()` but it ends there and I never hit the reducer to perform the actual state change.

If I, however, do the following, it works fine:

```
class MyComponent1 extends Component {

   ... Code omitted for brevity
   componentWillUnmount() {

      this.props.actions.cleanUpX();
      this.props.actions.cleanUpY();
      this.props.actions.cleanUpZ();
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens because the imported action creators are not bound to `dispatch` (unlike their counterparts on `this.props.actions`), so calling them simply returns an action object without triggering the reducer.

You can manually inject `dispatch` to your props and then pass it to the `cleanup` function, but the easiest solution is to install [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), and write your action creator like this:

```
export const cleanUp = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(cleanupX());
  dispatch(cleanupY());
  dispatch(cleanupZ());
};
```

Then you bind it at `connect` like you did for the other action creators, and call it from the component with `this.props.actions.cleanUp()`.

Installation of `redux-thunk` is straightforward, just install the npm package and add it to the middleware of your store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import yourReducer from ...;

const store = createStore(
  yourReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```